# Error grabbing OSM with ggmap and R

Tags: r, openstreetmap, ggmap

I have a loop (it is pretty long code, I will spare you) that reads a set of geographic coordinates from data and then uses them to download an OpenStreetMap: the line achieving this is as follows:

```
  newmap2<-get_openstreetmap(bbox = c(left = bbleft, bottom = bbbottom, right = bbright, top = bbtop),scale=80000)
```

the loop is supposed to run 82 times, as that is the number of different coordinates sets I have. After a variable number of cycles, (4 to 10) I get the following error:

> Error: map grabbing failed - see details in ?get_openstreetmap.

I suppose this is due to temporary unavailability of the server. Is there a way to stop and repeat the request until a successful download occurs, rather than the code aborting?

Comment: wrap the `get....` in a `try` with a test for a successful download? And add a small `Sys.sleep` to wait a bit?

Comment: Ok thanks, I will research that and try.

Comment: It did not work...

Comment: newmap2<-try(get_openstreetmap(bbox = c(left = bbleft, bottom = bbbottom, right = bbright, top = bbtop),scale=80000))
  Sys.sleep(30)